# Possibility of monitoring internet traffic in case where galaxy tab is used as a mobile access point?

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-tethering, data-monitoring

My employer gave me the Galaxy Tab. I am using it as a mobile access point (Wi-Fi) connection for my home computer. I do not have other internet access.

I would like to know if my employer can monitor my internet activity (see my email, visit sites I have visited, etc.) ?

Answer (score 1):

This depends completely on their mobile plan and how they have set up the tablet. AFAIK, *most* internet tethering apps **do not** collect activity, but *theoretically* their mobile provider could be monitoring the activity on their connection and reporting it back to your employer. However, there are too many factors here to give you a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, from the employer side, he can know the amount of traffic you've spend, if your using a data plan, but not where you spend it.

A data plan provider would have to violate some privacy rules/laws to collect such information.

Comment: I don't think the OP meant measuring traffic volume but looking for surfing habits and general spying on emails, chat, torrenting and such...

Comment: @ce4 My last paragraph then! I'll switch it to the top :)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there's no surveillance.
Android's corporate device management support is still in its infancy.

In case you got it pre-setup'ed for you you can wipe/factory reset it. You're then sure you got rid of whatever setup was done by anyone after the tablet has been bought.

But before you do this:

- Check for device management software.
  Settings -> Security -> Device administrators.
  You could look for stuff like mobile iron (used to enforce policies and monitor installed apps and such on company owned or BYOD  phones/tablets).
- Check for a configured VPN connection.
  Settings -> wireless&networks -> more -> VPN.
  Your company might have set up a VPN that routes **all** traffic including tethered traffic through company servers. Monitoring could be done there then.
- Check for a Microsoft Exchange profile.
  This can only be used to remote-wipe your tablet, there are however no further options for device management and monitoring.